# Error installing SDO_DAS_XML library

Tags: php, xml, static-libraries, fedora, sdo

I have been trying to install SDO_DAS_XML library in PHP5, but gives me an error as below

command: pecl install SCA_SDO

**Error:**

> 194 source files, building   running: phpize    Cannot find config.m4.
>   Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source
>   directory of the module
>
> ERROR: `phpize' failed

Operating system: Fedora 14

Note: installed pear and php-devel